# When was a document added to a MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb

I have an existing mongodb collection, which doesn't have any information about when the document was created.

Is it possible to get this information some how? I've had a look through the docs but can't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the default `ObjectId` value for your `_id` attribute, the creation time is encoded inside it.

As stated in [the ObjectID documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/):

> ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:
>
> - a 4-byte value representing the **seconds since the Unix epoch,**
> - a 3-byte machine identifier
> - a 2-byte process id, and a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

You can call the `getTimestamp()` function on an `ObjectId` object to get an `ISODate` object containing the creation time of the object:

*In the mongo shell:*

```js
ObjectId().getTimestamp()
ISODate("2014-05-14T14:29:12Z")
```

Comment: Better explanation that I could type in a minute.

Comment: unfortunately the _id is used. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @JimJeffries - You mean you have inserted your own custom `_id` value? Are you not using `ObjectId` at all?

Answer (score 2):

There is most likely the actual `_id` value of the document unless you have replaced this with something else.

In the simple "JavaScript" syntax of this ( and various methods are available to other languages) you simply access this as:

```js
var id = new ObjectId();
id.getTimetstamp();
```

Various language implementations have a way of retrieving the "timestamp" from an `ObjectId` value so you can just use that.